# Как создать файл excel по данным другого файла xls

Tags: python, excel, xlsx

А если точнее, то:

1. открыть шаблон (xlsx, внутри форма отчета, с ключами в формате {price},{id}...
2. Открыть файл с данными. Значения в файле с данными расположены одной строчкой, просто разные столбцы.
3. Заменить все ключи в файле шаблоне на значения из файла с данными.
4. Сохранить заполненный шаблон как новый док.
   И так для всех строчек файла с данными.
   1 строчка в файле с данными = 1 файл готовый.

Как лучше решить эту задачку?

Comment: Чуть подробнее о "файле данных". Это тоже xlsx? Или какоё-то CSV или docx?

Comment: Блин вроде думал ничего не упустил. Да xlsx.

Comment: ОК, как насчёт того, чтобы Шаблон выдрать из файла шаблона и поместить здесь же, в книге со списком данных, на соседнем листе? Хоть эта задача и сильно напоминает "Список рассылки" (Mail Merge) для Word'а, но для её реализации в Excel есть несколько довольно простых решений... Кстати, а зачем целевые ячейки помечены так странно {price},{id}?...

Comment: Да почти тоже самое, что и списки рассылки. В общем есть данные, по этим данным нужно сформировать печатные формы в excel на основании шаблона. А по поводу меток в шаблоне, я это для примера указал просто. Можно в принципе ставить любые метки. В принципе задачу решил, но очень костыльно получилось. Сформированные файлы на основе шаблона можно и в качестве листов ставить, принципиальной разницы нет.

Comment: Согласен, разницы почти никакой - только в случае отдельной книги-шаблона её нужно каждый раз дёргать с диска через `.Open`, а в случае "лист здесь же" - просто через `.Copy` создавать новую книгу сразу в памяти. Для короткого списка это действительно несущественно. И насчёт "костыльно" - если решение работает и делает то, что задумывалось, оно уже не может считаться плохим ИМХО